# Pasar datos entre formularios, a DataGridView dentro de varios contenedores C#

Tags: c#

mucho saludo y de ate manos gracias a todos que le dedican un tiempo a ver esta publicación y gracias al que me pueda ayudar.
Estoy tratando de pasar unos datos de dos textbox que tengo en el Form2, aquí pongo el código del botón, pero me da error.
Ver quien me pueda ayudar.
En el **Form1** tengo Un DatagridView, es donde quiero pasar los datos, pero la ruta me da error El **DatagridView** se encuentras dentro de un **TabPanel1**, contenido en el **TapControl1**, este a su vez estas dentro de un **Panel1** de un **SplitContainer1**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del Botón en el Form2 para pasar datos al Form1

```
private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 dato = new Form1 ();
        foreach (Form crl in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (crl.Name == " Form1 ")
            {
                dato = (Form1)crl;
                dato.splitContainer1.Panel1.TabControl1.tabPage1.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(txtNombre.Text, txtApellido.Text);

                this.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: El error que me da me dice esto " SplintterPanel no contiene una definición para el Tabcontrol " A partir del tabPanel me da el error

Comment: He añadido una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres pasar datos entre formularios, lo que yo hago usualmente es algo como esto (suponiendo que quieres pasar un `string`):

```
//Evento
private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  //valores de los TextBox:
  string textoTextBoxA = txtBoxA.Text;
  string textoTextBoxB = txtBoxB.Text;

  //Formulario al que le quieres pasar los datos con un botón:
  FormularioB frmB = new FormularioB(textoTextBoxA, textoTextBoxB);
  frmB.Show();
}
```

Entonces, en tu **FormularioB** tienes que recibir los parámetros:

```
public FormularioB(string txtA, string txtB)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  //resto de tu codigo
}
```

Un posible error en tu código sea esto:

```
if (crl.Name == " Form1 ")
```

Debería ser:

```
if (crl.Name == "Form1")
```

Sin los espacios.

Comment: muchas gracias me ha servido para otra duda tu ejemplo, pero en realidad mi problema esta en la ruta. voy a tratar de pasar el proyecto que tengo

Comment: Pues, es difícil de saber exáctamente donde está el error puesto que no se tiene el código completo ni el formulario

Comment: (https://mega.nz/file/Z8tEzZCY#PDRigoBUVMJZe0FN9oOhrSRQ3u6R0cP-EBYondu23vs), veo que el problema es mi código, ya que hice una pequeña aplicación con el caso y sigue igual, ver si tiene un poco de tiempo y le hecha un vistazo.

Comment: Deberías haberlo puesto en GitHub pero deja lo checo y vemos que hay